# How to access Global.resx file in App_GlobalResources

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 3 files in App_GlobalResources. I want to access 1 file based on my project.So I want to access it from app.Config file.Please give the code ,how to setup this requirement.

Comment: I want to access it in app.config file??? what does this mean. Could you be more clear asking your question.

Comment: I have 3 files. I have to use 1 file in one project.So its better to put its name in app.config file

Comment: I have 2 resources file with same culture.So how to access these resources file based on requirement.  @hnanu.cs